# Framework that uses DTOs or beans to create a databse

Tags: java, frameworks, persistence

Is there a java framework which given a class with data members (including objects like arraylists) will create a table in a given database and be able to insert and select these entities from said database? I know about ORMs which given a table and DTO can map rows to entities, but is there a framework which will create the tables for you as well?

Comment: I think we dont have any framework to generate or create the tables in databases

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two of the most popular open source persistence frameworks, iBATIS and Hibernate by RedHat. We have something called Java Persistence API (JPA) and JPA2 by Sun-Oracle.

JPA itself has features that will make up for a standard ORM framework. That said you can use JPA alone in a project.

Hibernate is the most popular ORM framework, once the JPA got introduced hibernate conforms to the JPA specifications. Apart from the basic set of specification that it should follow hibernate provides whole lot of additional stuff.